# storybook-readme does not load .md

Tags: reactjs, storybook, readme

I'm trying to use the storybook-readme addon and it does not render the readme file content.

[image: Readme is not rendered]

This is my configuration:

.storybook/preview.js
[image: .storybook/preview.js]

.storybook/main.js
[image: .storybook/main.js]

TextInput.stories.js
[image: TextInput.stories.js]

I have to mention that the readme file only contains ###Usage for testing purposes